# AdMob interstitial doesn't show on Android

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android app and I'm trying to add AdMob interstitials into it. I create them this way

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad));
interstitial.loadAd(AdUtils.createRequest());
```

and when the moment is appropriate, I show them like this:

```
if(interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
}
```

When I test this code on the emulator, everything is fine. But when I run it on the real device, it often (about a half of all shows) displays only a black screen with the close button and no advertisement image at all. Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below.

Declare this as a variable.

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
```

then use this part in your `onCreate` method

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "your id");

// Create ad request
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();  

// Begin loading your interstitial
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

// Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
interstitial.setAdListener(this);
```

and at last set this outside your `onCreate` method so basically set below code in your activity..

```
@Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (ad == interstitial) {
              interstitial.show();
            }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks, but I use Google Play version of Mobile Ads SDK, which is slightly different from your version